# To extract images from website

Tags: android

How to extract images from website and display in grid or list view?

Answer (score 1):

```
Bitmap bmImg;
    void downloadfile(String fileurl,ImageView img)
    {
        URL myfileurl =null;
        try
        {
            myfileurl= new URL(fileurl);

        }
        catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        try
        {
            HttpURLConnection conn= (HttpURLConnection)myfileurl.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.connect();
            int length = conn.getContentLength();
            int[] bitmapData =new int[length];
            byte[] bitmapData2 =new byte[length];
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            options.inSampleSize = 
            bmImg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is,null,options);

            img.setImageBitmap(bmImg);

            //dialog.dismiss();
            } 
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
//          Toast.makeText(PhotoRating.this, "Connection Problem. Try Again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
```

try this

Answer (score 0):

This [url](http://www.androidkit.com/loading-images-from-remote-server-over-http-on-a-separate-thread) explains about downloading images from remote server using asynchronous task and displaying  downloaded images in  a list view.

Answer (score 0):

below code helps you to get the image . if you pass the url of the image.

```
      public Drawable loadImageFromWebOperations(String url)
{

     try
     {

         DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(url);  
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGetRequest);  
        InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();


         Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src name");

         return d;

     }   catch (Exception e) {

         System.out.println("Exc="+e);

         return null;

     }

 }
```

This code will return you a drawable which you can display in ImageView

```
      imageView.setImageDrawable(d);
```

you can add an ImageView to each row of the List and set the drawable.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to parse the whole websites, I prefer to use [Jerico HTML Parser](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html), it's works fine with Android (tried), then you can search for `<img>` elements to get the image urls.